# Can't populate layout with JSON data

Tags: android, json, android-layout, android-fragments, retrofit

I'm trying to populate a layout of mine by looping through some requested JSON (I use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)).

When I try to populate the layout manually (like below), it displays fine:

```
Post post1 = new Post("1", "1", "This is a message.");
```

But if I try to populate it with the requested JSON data, the layout doesn't get populated nor does it display on my screen. Only the layout with "This is a message." is displayed.

Here is the code within my `onCreateView()` for my fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_posts);

    final ArrayList<Post> arrayOfUsers = new ArrayList<Post>();

    // This works fine. It populates the layout as it should.
    Post post1 = new Post("1", "1", "This is a message.");
    arrayOfUsers.add(post1);

    final RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
            .build();

    final ApiEndpointInterface apiService = restAdapter.create(ApiEndpointInterface.class);

    apiService.getJsonStuff(1, new Callback<PostData>() {

        @Override
        public void success(PostData postData, Response response) {

            // This doesn't work either
            Post post2 = new Post("1", "1", "This is a message2.");
            arrayOfUsers.add(post2);

            for (Post p : postData.data) {

                // This does not work. The layout isn't populated nor does it display.
                Post posty = new Post(p.getId(), p.getUserId(), p.getContent());
                arrayOfUsers.add(posty);

                // The JSON is being read correctly, since this prints out the right values.
                Log.d("MESSAGE", p.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
            retrofitError.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    PostAdapter adapter = new PostAdapter(getActivity(), arrayOfUsers);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}
```

The callback:

```
void getJsonStuff(@Path("user_id") int userId, Callback<PostData> response);
```

`Post` model:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Post {

    @Expose
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("user_id")
    @Expose
    private String userId;
    @Expose
    private String content;

    public Post(String id, String userId, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.content = content;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The id
     */
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param id
     * The id
     */
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The userId
     */
    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param userId
     * The user_id
     */
    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The content
     */
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param content
     * The content
     */
    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content= content;
    }

}
```

`PostData` model:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;

public class PostData {

    @Expose
    public Boolean success;
    @Expose
    public List<Post> data = new ArrayList<Post>();

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The success
     */
    public Boolean getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param success
     * The success
     */
    public void setSuccess(Boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The data
     */
    public List<Post> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param data
     * The data
     */
    public void setData(List<Post> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you post pojo class ?

Comment: callback must be same with your pojo class  Post

Comment: @andiyulistyo Added the class to the question.

Comment: @andiyulistyo Forgot one of the classes. Added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the scenario that works for you -> you are doing the things sequentially: create the Post object - add it to the list - create the adapter based on the non-empty list - set the adapter on the list.

In the scenario that doesn't work, you are doing them asynchronously: create empty list - trigger request for data (but no data yet) - create adapter - set the adapter on the list - at some undetermined moment in the future data arrives. The problem is that in this case the adapter doesn't know that anything changed, so you need to notify it (at the end of your `success` callback):
`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by sequentially and asynchronously. Is one better than the other? Should I be doing one but not the other?

Comment: You are downloading things. Asynchronuosly is of course the choice. But you get it automatically in this case. In this scenario you basically are saying to the apiService "go get the data I need and notify me when you get it; in the meantime I am going to go ahead and do other stuff (initialize the adapter, set it to the list view and basically getting out of `onCreate`), so the UI is not locked waiting for you. When you're done, please give me the data so that I can notify the interested parties (adapter)".

Answer (score 0):

Your `getJsonStuff` method should be declared something like...

```
getJsonStuff(int id, Callback<List<Post>> callback)
```

Comment: Ok, one more thing...this line is useless Post posty = new Post(p.getId(), p.getUserId(), p.getContent()); You should only call arrayOfUsers.add(p); instead.

Comment: I tried both suggestions, neither got the JSON data to populate an display the layout. I edited my original question to show that putting `Post post2 = new Post("1", "1", "This is a message2.");` within the `success` callback doesn't work either. Also, I think the callback should be using `PostData`, not `Post`, no?

Comment: Mmm....is really the success method get called? Where have you declared the getMessage() method in the Post class? What's the output of this Log.d("MESSAGE", p.getId()); Log.d("MESSAGE", p.getUserId()); Log.d("MESSAGE", p.getContent());

Comment: Yes, I've checked that the success callback is being called. All of the console logs print the correct data.

Comment: What about the getMessage method?

Comment: In addition to @N.T. answer...you should initialize your adapter in your success method.